# How to pass params from a function to a bootstrap modal to an action method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

OnCheckedChanged function gets triggered when a radio button gets selected in a table of multiple rows. Each row represents details about a book.
The "bn" param is a book number.

The thing is I have to display a certain message inside the modal but only after I got a result from the action method showBook, because the message to be displayed depends on the bn value. After the message is displayed in modal, if the user chooses to delete the book, new action method needs to be called, and again we need to pass this bn parameter to another action method.

How to pass this bn to the modal and again to the action method inside modal? I'm using Asp.net MVC in case that can make things easier.

```
function OnCheckedChanged(bn) {        
        var url = "/book/showBook?bookNumber=" + bn;
            $.get(url, function (result) {                
                $("#showBookModal").modal('show', function () {  
    //so now I need to tell the modal to display the details about the book, 
    //and the details are in a result, I don't know how to                   
                });
        });        
    }

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Book title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>display details about the book here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">delete this book</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to use alternative script, for example, with fancybox (http://fancyboxjs.com/) you could just do smth like `$.fancybox.open({type: 'html', src:'<p>Your HTML</p>'});` (fancybox can do ajax request for you, too).

Comment: I may not add other libraries

Answer (score 0):

if detail is not received in `result`. then how would you show the detail to the modal. Once you received the detail in result you can do as below:

```
function OnCheckedChanged(bn) {        
        var url = "/book/showBook?bookNumber=" + bn;
            $.get(url, function (result) {                
                $("#showBookModal").modal('show', function () {  
    //so now I need to tell the modal to display the details about the book, 
    //and the details are in a result, I don't know how to    
                  $('#pDetails').text(result);
                });
        });        
    }

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Book title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="pDetails"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">delete this book</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to postpone showing the modal until the result is returned? or I can add loading spinner inside the <p>?

Comment: `if(result === true){  $('#pDetails').text(result); }`

Comment: It's not helping, it's not displayed at all